# GPS too inaccurate

Tags: java, android, gps

I am new in android devlopment and I am trying to create a lap counting app.
In favor I calculate a distance (finishline) and look for intersections with toher distances (two latest coordinates).

My Problem is that my gps coordinates got 3.0 m (radius) accuracy in best case and this this is not enough.

Do you have any idea how to improve my accuracy? or is there a smarter way to count laps?

help and advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: 3 meters accuracy from public GPS seems pretty good. If you really need that good precision I'm not sure an android app without specialized hardware is the right way to go.

Comment: It is very good accuracy. Why do you need better?

Comment: well, I am drawing a finishline (like 2 meters) and if I am unlucky and got a great inaccuracy my whole app will work wrong (dont count laps or count laps at the wrong place). For now I was only testing in the city, maybe I wont get this 3 meters if i go to woods or smth like that ....

Comment: I think you need to focus on the provider as well, If you using GPS as provider will give you best results then the NETWORK Provider.

Comment: @RajaPeela ya if i use Network its like 30-50 meters ...

Comment: You need a professional instruments for more accuracy. The limit is hw not sw.

Comment: ` if i go to woods or smth like that ` - that sounds like you don't actually need _that_ high a precision. You'd just have to deal with the missed finish line IMHO. In that case just make the finish bigger so you can't miss it, a few meters more or less shouldn't make a huge difference.

Comment: @Thomas "if i go to woods or smth like that " was just a example for an outdoorplace not in city. Atm I test my app with a lap around 400 meters and it already counts lapS (it mostly counts 4 laps instead of one) at the wrong places - so if I increase my finishline the counter of wrong laps will ncrease too. But thanks for helping

Comment: 3 meters is pretty good for non-military GPS without correctional sensor data. I'm afraid you'll need to refine your algorithms.

Comment: You can get fused locations to get the best of both worlds, gps and network locations: https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation secondly, location updates has an accuracy value, which u can use to filter out those of high inaccuracies. This was enough for me to determine intersection with geofences of down to 30 meters while driving. I'm almost sure it should suffice for your case as well.

Comment: And as mentioned by others, you cannot expect much improvement in accuracy. Handling the inaccuracies in code is the way to go, otherwise you should look for specialized equipment like ibeacons or similar.

Comment: @cYrixmorten i ll try to improve my algorithm - I was also thinking about geofences but thougt intersections with distances should be more accurate besides the app should be availabel for pedestrian, too. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this comment became too long so posting as an answer although it is more in the form of a suggestion.

Without going into much detail, you can use activity recognition to determine wheter the user is walking, running, driving. Using this information, keep a hold on the 'good quality' location updates and use a combination of accuracy and assumed max velocity based on activity to detect poor quality location updates.

This idea might be extended to perform dead reconing in areas where the location updates are too inaccurate.

I have added Activity Recognition to the library https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation, greatly reducing the code needed to get it up and running.